# Should Angular's AfterContentChecked or AfterViewChecked run after all child components have finished running AfterContentChecked or AfterViewChecked?

Tags: angular

I know that in React ComponentDidMount of a parent component will run after all children ComponentDidMounts have run. It seems like this is not the default behavior from Angular (2+) with AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit, or AfterContentChecked. I inherited a project that has a specific set up so it's possible there's something going on there that I don't realize.

My current solution is using a setTimeout in the parent component AfterViewInit (since no other lifecycle method worked I stuck it there) and I want to know if Angular has this same feature as React and maybe I am just missing it.

Comment: afterViewchecked is called after change detector has completed checking a component's view for changes. So it has to wait for all children components to complete checking as well. Otherwise, it does not make sense, right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep in mind the difference between view and content — content is being checked first, it is whatever your component is wrapped around (`my-nested-comp` here):

```
<my-comp>
  <my-nested-comp><my-nested-comp>
</my-comp>
```

After Angular has done that, it would run `ngAfterContentInit`. Then if in the template of `my-comp` there are some other components it is going to run through them, also starting with their content and then their views, all bottom up. After that `ngAfterViewInit` will be executed. Also at this point you can reliably start working with `@ViewChild/ren`s.

Then the same stuff happens on each change detection cycle, except these hooks are called `ngAfterContentChecked`/`ngAfterViewChecked`. Change detection goes bottom up so if you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in nested components and their inputs haven't changed, it would not go any deeper.

Comment: I guess I was looking more for something that cared about when the html had rendered. From my experience AfterContentChecked/AfterViewChecked don't do that and it sounds like that's not the intention at all anyway. I was just hoping for equivalent functionality from ComponentDidMount in react

Comment: Well, usually at the time of AfterViewInit everything is rendered fine, perhaps something inside nested views has some delays, setTimeouts or animations?